# iOS layer animation stops abruptly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, core-animation, calayer

I am trying to use the animation from this library:
https://github.com/shu223/PulsingHalo

I have a UIScrollView, and within it a UIImageView that has a larger width

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    scrollView  = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView = scrollView;
    [self.view insertSubview:scrollView belowSubview:self.optionsButton];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.mapImageView = imageView;
    UIImage* mapImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."];
    // Add image (larger than screen size) to the image view.
    [imageView setImage: mapImg];

// Set the constraints for the scroll view and the image view.
    NSDictionary* viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, imageView);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imageView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

After this, I add a bunch of buttons to my scrollview, programmatically. For instance:

```
UIButton* flagButton = [UIButton new];
[self.scrollView addSubview: flagButton];
flagButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSLayoutConstraint* xc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:flagButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mapImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.f constant:x];
NSLayoutConstraint* yc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:flagButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mapImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.f constant:y];
[self.view addConstraints@[xc, yc]];
```

Now I want to create my halo for this button. I create a specific view for it, centered around my button. I still haven't quite wrapped my head around positioning, so I don't position it for now.

```
UIView* haloView = [UIView new];
haloView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
NSLayoutConstraint* constraintHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:haloView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:flagButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:2.0 constant:0.f];
NSLayoutConstraint* constraintWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:haloView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:flagButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:2.0 constant:0.f];
NSLayoutConstraint* constraintCenterX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:haloView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:flagButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.f];
NSLayoutConstraint* constraintCenterY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:haloView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:flagButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.f];
[self.view insertSubview:haloView belowSubview:flagButton];
haloView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
constraintCenterX.active = YES;
constraintCenterY.active = YES;
constraintHeight.active = YES;
constraintWidth.active = YES;
PulsingHaloLayer *halo = [PulsingHaloLayer layer];
[haloView.layer insertSublayer:halo atIndex:0];
halo.radius = 50.0;
halo.haloLayerNumber = 4;
halo.duration = 4.0;
```

This should normally provide me with the pulsing animation shown in the linked library. And I do get it, somewhat. The behavior is hard to describe, but it appears to start correctly, then abruptly stop when it should loop, then restart again a second later. Basically, it does not seem to loop properly as it should, and I have no idea why.

This is the view hierarchy. The last "UIView" is the one with the Halo layer.
[image: View hierarchy]

These are the UIView's properties as shown by the debugger.
[image: UIView properties]

These are the UIScrollView's properties.
[image: UIScrollView properties]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You forgot to use `haloLayerNumber` property, try     `halo.haloLayerNumber = 3`; the default is 1, so you see no loop.

Comment: I did try setting a haloLayerNumber, and this does not change anything.

Comment: It changes dramatically for me, share more of your code.

Comment: I tested this in a single view app without a scrollview and it works fine. I think my specific setup may mess with it, or something I am not taking into account. I have added information on the view hierarchy and properties.